# Remove RunAs->Local C/C++ Application from Eclipse Product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

We are developing a development and testing platform for C projects in Eclipse platform. However, i need to remove RunAs->Local C/C++ Application from the Eclipse UI.
I am adding CDT plug-in in dependencies in the EClipse.Prodcut and tried to to remove the  RunAs->Local C/C++ Application by removing org.eclipse.debug.ui and org.eclipse.debug.core from the dependecy page but is it not hiding the RunAs->Local C/C++ Application.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

you might have a look on Eclipse RCP Activities mechanism. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/). you also need to investigate if CDT defines any activities for its menu actions and if so, deactivate some.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried in this way but still did not get the desired result. Is there any other way?

Comment: if it cannot be done programatically, and since Eclipse CDT and other plugins are EPL-licensed (LGPL style, kind of), you can always hack its plugin.xml and remove the actions from the toolbars yourself. you'd have to include sources of hacked plugins in documentation though..

Comment: I'll try to hack the plugin.xml. Thanks for your Input.